# Multiple Rows in INSERTED table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

On a table in MS SQL Server I need to run a CLR Stored Procedure on new rows if those rows meet certain criteria.  I thought that would be more or less straightforward:

```
if ((SELECT Cabinet FROM INSERTED) = 1 OR (SELECT Cabinet FROM INSERTED) = 3) AND (SELECT Result_02 FROM INSERTED) = 'N'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id int
    SET @id = (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED)
    exec PrintLabel
        @id,
        N'LP 2844 LGE'
END;
```

However, this recently started throwing errors about a subquery returning multiple rows. I learned that INSERT triggers run once for each statement, not necessarily on individual rows. So, that IF statement can be working on multiple rows, and thus the error.

My question is: how can I iterate over each new row if the rows are added in a batch (in this case via a MERGE statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a stored procedure for N rows still requires a cursor.

```
declare @id int
declare cur cursor fast_forward for 
    select  id 
    from    inserted 
    where   Cabinet in (1,3)
open cur
fetch next from cur into @id
while @@fetch_status = 0   
    begin
    exec PrintLabel @id, N'LP 2844 LGE'
    fetch next from cur into @id
    end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: while this will work, it would be far better to rewrite the proc to handle multiple row inputs. If someohomw a million records got changed, this woudl tie up your table for a long long time. An alternative method is to copy the records from inserted to processing table and havea job that runs every five minuntes that iterates through the records and then removes them from the processing table. This at least removes the cursor from the trigger.